# Adding a string as an object to an already existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts

I'm building a dynamic [xChart](http://tenxer.github.com/xcharts/examples/). The dynamic data I'm passing is a pre-built string ready to be converted to an object by js:

```
{"data": [{"x":"car insurance companies","y":1417},
          {"x":"insurance companies","y":17201},
          {"x":"auto insurance companies","y":892},
          {"x":"car insurance quote","y":3280},
          {"x":"auto insurance quote","y":988}]}
```

Here's a sample snippet of parameter code that xCharts needs:

```
var data = {
  "xScale": "ordinal",
  "yScale": "linear",
  "main": [
    {
      "className": ".pizza",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": "Pepperoni",
          "y": 4
        },
        {
          "x": "Cheese",
          "y": 8
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

And here is MY set of parameters:

```
var vars = {
    "xScale": "ordinal",
    "yScale": "linear",
    "type": "bar",
    "main": [
    {
        "className": ".topsy-results"
    }
    ]
};
```

I need to add my `data` object to the `main` object in my parameter list to make it complete. If I `$.parseJSON` the `data` object it gives me an object of objects which will not work. How do I parse the `data` object to get the format I need (to make it match the sample code I gave)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$.extend` and just merge the two?

```
var prebuilt = {...}; //that pre-build data
var vars = {...}; // Your vanilla settings

var merged = $.extend({}, vars, {
  'main': prebuilt
});
```

I've placed `prebuilt` in to another object so the nesting works out when it's extended , but now `prebuilt` should show within `data` of the `merged` object. *Note:* `$.extend` is useful if you have more than just the data information or if there are existing pieces in the `data` property already and you want to either update them or add new ones).

You can also simply assign it just by reference:

```
vars.main.data = prebuilt.data;
```

Comment: This definitely adds the data object to the original object but the main issue I am having is that each "set" of data inside the data object is also parsed as an object. I don't want that.

Comment: @JaredEitnier: in your example, `data` is an array of objects, so I'm confused by what you're looking for. From what i see, they _should_ be objects.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right - I was looking at the data wrong. everything you've provided works properly. I may have an issue with the actual data I'm passing, so I'll take a closer look at that now.

Comment: Got it figured out. I had to add it using `vars.main[0].data = prebuilt.data`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can just add it on the fly by assigning the *data* property to the *main*:

```
var myData={"data": [{"x":"car insurance companies","y":1417},
          {"x":"insurance companies","y":17201},
          {"x":"auto insurance companies","y":892},
          {"x":"car insurance quote","y":3280},
          {"x":"auto insurance quote","y":988}]};
vars.main.data = myData.data;
console.log(vars);
```